# LightBox2 hides behind HTML iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, lightbox2

I am trying to show a whole page using an iFrame, but after 5 seconds, I want a LightBox to pop up over the iFrame. The problem I'm having is that the iFrame is on top of the LightBox pop-up and I have no idea how to make it the other way around.

I was reading that if the iFrame source has a flash player, that could be the cause; but there is no Flash anywhere on the page. I've been tinkering with things for over a hour and cannot figure out what I'm not doing.

This is the page with the iFrame:
[iFrame](http://www.gatewaywd.com/cj/iframe.html)

This is the page without the iFrame: [No iFrame](http://www.gatewaywd.com/cj/noiframe.html)

I know the timer and the LightBox pop-up are working, they're just hiding behind the iFrame. Any ideas as to what is wrong?

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var count = 5;
    var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);

    function timer() {
        count = count - 1;
        if (count <= 0) {
            clearInterval(counter);
            $("#showFB").trigger('click');
            return;
        }
    }
});


</script>
<a id="showFB" href="img/globe.png" data-lightbox="image-1" title="" style="display:none">i</a>

<iframe title="ats" style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:visible; z-index:999999;" src="http://www.automatedtrafficsuite.com/login"></iframe>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have z-index problem

give bigger value to z-index of lightbox

in **lightbox.css** on line 8

```
z-index: 999999;
```

in **lightbox.css** on line 20

```
z-index: 1000000;
```

Comment: I have to wait 6 minutes, but I will.